How to make a small server at home with a power edge M360
I have 2 PowerEdge M360 blades from Dell without the power supply and without racks. I want to install them at home to make a personnal server.
Here are the specs: https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/aa/Dell-PowerEdge-M630-Spec-Sheet.pdf
I would like to find a small rack or a case to put the two blades into. But I cannot find any product that fits the need. Or maybe there is a better solution?

As it is mentioned in the first lines of the document you link you need:
PowerEdge M1000e blade enclosure
W/o enclosure you will have no power supply, no networking and no management interface (and IMHO no CD/DVD). The enclosure is much more than just rack.
